# Handling TextInput events in React Native

Tags: react-native

How can we handle two events at the same time for React Native text input? For example, in my  component I want the text to change when I am typing and submit when I am hit enter. I tried with the code below and it did not work but I think that's the idea

```
<TextInput onChangeText={this.functionA} onSubmitEditing={this.functionB}></TextInput>
```

Comment: Can you clarify what you're asking? Your example is exactly how you would do it...

Comment: I tried some code like that and it did not work so I am not sure if we can use 2 event handlers at once for a component

Answer (score 1):

Here what i have done testing and checking for you.

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import { AppRegistry, TextInput, View } from 'react-native';

export default class UselessTextInput extends Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = { text: 'Useless Placeholder' };
  }

  functionA(){
    alert('AAA');
  }

  functionB(){
    alert('BBB');
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <View style={{paddingTop:40}}>
      <TextInput
        style={{height: 40, borderColor: 'gray', borderWidth: 1}}
        // onChangeText={(text) => this.setState({text})}

        onChangeText={this.functionA} onSubmitEditing={this.functionB}

        value={this.state.text}
      />
      </View>
    );
  }
}
```

Please make sure you have read the [Document](https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/textinput.html#onchangetext)
And moreover, you should understand:

> **onChangeText** is called when the text input's text changes.

============

> **onSubmitEditing** is called when the text input's submit button is pressed.

Hope this will help you to figure and guide you more information.